# Add link with variable to a WooCommerce mail

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, printf

How do i make a printf function to display a html link filled with a woocommerce variable? See the code below:

```
<?php printf('<a href="https://www.baseclothing.nl/mijn-account/view-order/%s/">https://www.baseclothing.nl/mijn-account/view-order/%s/</a>', 'woocommerce', esc_html( $order->get_order_number() ) ); ?>
```

The link i get send to is https://www.baseclothing.nl/mijn-account/view-order/woocommerce/. The variable %s needs to be filled with the order number, so that when the link is clicked the user gets send to the correct order in his orders menu.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a variable to a link in a WooCommerce mail by using HTML with inline PHP:

```
<a href="https://example.com/view-order/<?php echo $order->get_order_number();?>/">View your order details.</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ord_number = 10; //esc_html( $order->get_order_number() )
printf('<a href="https://www.baseclothing.nl/mijn-account/view-order/%s/">https://www.baseclothing.nl/mijn-account/view-order/%s/</a>', 'woocommerce',  $ord_number);
```

This works fine. If any issues, please check your order number is getting properly before the printf.

**Tested OK**

Answer (score 0):

In your code, **Replace the unneeded `'woocommerce'`** by `esc_html( $order->get_order_number() )`, as the order number is required two times *(two same links)*:

```
<?php printf('<a href="https://www.baseclothing.nl/mijn-account/view-order/%s/">https://www.baseclothing.nl/mijn-account/view-order/%s/</a>', esc_html( $order->get_order_number() ), esc_html( $order->get_order_number() ) ); ?>
```

This will ovoid `woocommerce` to replace the needed order number in the link. The code works and has the correct link with the order number.

---

Now as you use the same link two times in your code, try this short version instead:

```
<?php $url = sprintf('https://www.baseclothing.nl/mijn-account/view-order/%s/', esc_html( $order->get_order_number() ) ); 
echo '<a href="'.$url.'">'.$url.'</a>'; ?>
```

Tested and works perfectly too.